# How to calculate the image, pdf, ppt, or doc file size which was uploaded by the user in php

Tags: php, image, file-upload, filesize

Once the user uploads the image, pdf doc, and ppt then I am displaying the file size on the page using below code and it's working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var fileName ;
$('.fileupload').change(function(e){
  fileName = e.target.files[0].name; // get file name
  var ext = fileName.split('.').pop();// check extention
  var filesize= formatBytes(this.files[0].size);
  $(this).closest(".upload_doc").find('.fileSizePreview').html(filesize);
  
});
function formatBytes(bytes, decimals = 2) {
    if (bytes === 0) return '0 Bytes';

    const k = 1024;
    const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
});
```

Now I have to calculate the upload image size so I tried the below code but not getting the correct output.

```
$filename="xyz.png"; // or xyz.pdf

echo filesize($filename) . ' bytes';

echo format_size('/home/u886461223/domains/domain.com/public_html/test/example/assets/images/uploads/myprofile/70x70_1941629672.png');

 function format_size($size) {
      $sizes = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
      if ($size == 0) { return('n/a'); } else {
      return (round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]); }
}
```

I have to display the output like

```
200Bytes, 1.5KB, 1MB
```

Comment: @cmd3BOT, I am getting the  n/a  and Warning: filesize(): stat failed for error

Comment: Actually, I was testing on localhost that's the reason I was getting the error. And now it's working on the server. Thank you for the help. Please upload your answer.